# R - remove everything after @ from the column

Tags: r

[image]

I would like to remove everything in the first column after the @. I tried all kinds of gsub functions but nothing seems to work. I have been able to get it to work for 1 string but there are 1.7k more.

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. Don't post images of code or error messages. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly. Also Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Comment: Try `stringr::str_remove(STATESC, "@.*$")`

Comment: Try `gsub("(\w+)@(.*)", "\\1@", STATESC)`.

Answer (score 1):

A tidyverse solution based on a look around can be implemented as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data <- tibble(STATESC = c('Illinois@Cook County', 'New York@Kings County'),
               TOT_FEMALE = c(261508, 253696))

data %>%
  mutate(STATESC = str_remove(STATESC, '(?<=@).*'))

#   STATESC   TOT_FEMALE
#   <chr>          <dbl>
# 1 Illinois@     261508
# 2 New York@     253696
```